# How do I subtract a value from each element of an array in Lua?

Tags: arrays, lua

I am trying to write a function to find the variance of a data set.

I am stuck on a small problem. I have an array, and I want to find how far each element in the array is from the average. Here is a simplified version of what I wrote:

```
>y={1,2,3}
>y_average=2
>y_diff={}

>for key, value in pairs(y) do y_diff[key]=(y[key]-y_average)
>>return unpack(y_diff)
>>end

-1
```

**what I want to get:** -1, 0, 1

Why does it only give me the first value and not all three?

Comment: your return will happen on the first iteration of the for loop and stop the loop from continuing. move the `return unpack(y_diff)` outside/below the loop's `end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return is breaking the loop in the first iteration as mentioned in a comment. Try this:

```
for  i in ipairs(y) do
    y_diff[i] = y[i] - y_average
end
print( table.concat(y_diff, '\t') )
```

table.concat doesn't have a limit on the amount of elements it can handle and it would be what you would use if you wanted to put these elements in a file faster than writing them one by one.

Comment: This does look better. I have a few questions though. Why did you write "i,_ in ipairs(y)" instead of "i,v in ipairs(y)" which is what I have seen before?

Also, it thought table.concat connects different tables together. What exactly is its the function here?

Comment: If you are talking about the underscore before ipairs it's what I use some a variable name (it's a valid variable name!) when I want to throw away a value. In this case it's redundant though because it's the second variable returned. I'll edit my code.